# How do I check if code is running from Visual Studio or from Automated Build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tfsbuild

We have a scenario wherein we have sql unit tests, for that we have a sql test project which reads connection string from App.config.

We now want that if we run test from Visual studio it should use ConnectionStringA else if it runs from Automated Build, it should use ConnectionStringB.

Can I somehow determine if the test is running under visualstudio or automated build ?

I have tried `Debugger.IsAttached` but that wont work if I try to run the test

I also tried to have a check on `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.ToLower()` but I am not sure if that is a fool proof way.

I researched about using `BuildingInsideVisualStudio` but cant get it to work.

Comment: First of all, what unit-test-runner are you using? That will go a long way to helping people answer your question. And as always, http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: o yea,, I am using Resharper with Visual studio, and default visual studio tfs build

Comment: added what I have tried till now

Comment: Why do you need to determine if the tests are running under VS or under build?
The build should update on build server the app.config with ConnectionStringB then will run the tests on the correct database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running TFS/VSTS you can look for any of the environment variables listed [on the build variables docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch), and use them to determine if you're local or not.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting an environment variable or registry value and reading it runtime?